# OpenGL recording frame buffer for 10 seconds and replay

Tags: opengl, glreadpixels

I am trying to make some OpenGL code to record 10 seconds of frame buffer and replay after recording is done.

What I am currently thinking is using glReadPixels and glDrawPixels on system memory. For 640 x 480 USB camera input stream, 10 seconds with 60 FPS is around 737 MB (640 x 480 x 4 x 60 x 10).

Do you think this is OK to do? I wonder how I can show saved images in 60 FPS again but I want to ask if this is doable thing first.

Comment: First, I have no idea what `glWritePixels (...)` is, but because `glReadPixels (...)` is normally synchronous you will have a hard time sustaining 60 FPS doing that. If you read into a PBO you can fix that problem though.

Comment: You might look at apitrace:  http://apitrace.github.io/

Comment: Lol sorry, Andon, it is glDrawPixels. :) I will edit my post.

Comment: You probably want to encode those frames or you're going to make a massive amount of data in a hurry. At the very least, save as PNG. Even better: H.264 encode a stream.

Comment: Thanks, tadman. I followed your guide and found a good way to do. I posted it below how I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found answer myself about this thing.

http://blog.mmacklin.com/2013/06/11/real-time-video-capture-with-ffmpeg/

This link shows very simple way of doing it without too much coding in the program. Very easy to do and very efficient as well.

FFMpeg is great tool.